# Loading a new page with Javascript/Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, forms

I have an Ajax script that allows me to check a form without refreshing the page. But i want it to check if fields haven't been complete, but if al fields are complete i want to send the user to a new page.

I'm not sure how i can do this. Here is the Ajax script:

```
function pass() 
{

// Real Browsers (chrome)

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
{
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
}

// IE

else if (window.ActiveXObject) 
{
    xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

//Store data
var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
var firstname = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
var surname = document.getElementById('surname').value;
var address1 = document.getElementById('address1').value;
var address2 = document.getElementById('address2').value;
var postcode = document.getElementById('postcode').value;

//Open POST location
xhr.open("POST","addUserSeminar.php");

xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');

//Make object to store all data
var obj = {email: email, firstname: firstname, surname: surname, address1: address1, address2: address2, postcode: postcode};

//Encode the data with JSON and send it to the server
xhr.send("data=" + JSON.stringify(obj));

//Check return state and change "myDiv"
xhr.onreadystatechange=function() 
{

    if (xhr.readyState==4) 
    {
        document.getElementById("settingsDiv").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    }

}

//Return false so form doesn't submit
return false;
}
```

It sends the data out to a php file where i check if the boxes are filled, if not i each a message like "Name not found". But if all data is posted then i add a record to my database and then return true.

How could i pick up that return in my Ajax script so i can test if its true, if so forward to a new page.

Thanks for the time.

Comment: try using `location.href = "new location url"`

Comment: Please, to protect your own soul, never create a XMLHttpRequest by yourself if it is not absolutly necessary. Use [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or something like that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

return the string "TRUE" from server side on success

PHP CODE

```
if($valid_inputs) { // all input fields are valid
   echo "TRUE";
} else {
   echo "FALSE";
}
```

client side JS code

```
if (xhr.readyState==4) 
{
    if (xhr.responseText.indexOf("TRUE") > -1) {
      window.location = "redirecturl.php"; //redirect url
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, This did work, but i had a bug in my php, i was using return true instead of echo "true" Thanks for your help.

Comment: welcome, 
indexOf will return a value >=0 if string exist you an use >=0 instad of > -1 also.

Answer (score 1):

Return back something from the server that says it is complete and read it with the xhr.responseText in an if statement.

```
if( xhr.responseText.indexOf("forward to next page") > -1 ){
    //forward
} else {
   //show error message
}
```

It would be a lot better if you used a JSON object to return errors and success messages, since you could just check the object to waht to do.

Answer (score 1):

In your onreadystatechanged, readyState == 4 if block...

```
if(xhr.responseText.indexOf("SUCCESS") >= 0) {
    window.location.href = NEW_URI;
} else {
    document.getElementById("settingsDiv").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
}
```

Have your PHP script return a unique string to denote SUCCESS vs FAILURE with fields that are blank.